Manage Dependencies in Sub-Project To Avoid Duplicate React Versions
I am attempting to create a React library template. I have the main project that exports some basic React hooks and then an example project enclosed within it that imports the library via "@local/lib": "file:.." in the package.json file.
Both projects depend on React 18.3.1, so they currently both have the dependencies of "react": "^18.3.1" and "react-dom": "^18.3.1". However, this causes an issue where using the hooks causes the following message:
index.js:163 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Looking at that page, it looks like the most likely cause is duplicate React versions, so I updated the example project's React dependencies to read "react": "file:../node_modules/react" and "react-dom": "file:../node_modules/react-dom", deleted the node_modules folder, and ran another install. The expectation is that this will allow my inner example project to use the same React version as the outer project, fixing the error I'm experiencing.
If I run npm ls react, it does seem like this is the case based on how I'm interpreting the output:
example@0.1.0 /home/ptolemy/webpages/npm/react-mount-effects/example
├─┬ @ptolemy2002/react-mount-effects@0.1.0 -> ./..
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.3.1
│ │ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
│ └── react@18.3.1
├─┬ react-dom@18.3.1 -> ./../node_modules/react-dom
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped
├─┬ react-error-boundary@4.0.13
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped -> ./../node_modules/react
├─┬ react-router-bootstrap@0.26.3
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped -> ./../node_modules/react
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.25.1
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.25.1
│ │ └── react@18.3.1 deduped -> ./../node_modules/react
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped -> ./../node_modules/react
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.3.1 deduped -> ./../node_modules/react
└── react@18.3.1 -> ./../node_modules/react

However, there is no change in behavior. The error is still shown, which means there must still be duplicate React versions if I understand correctly.
Full code for the library I'm developing to test the template can be found at https://github.com/Ptolemy2002/react-mount-effects.

It looks like the react and react-dom versions all match. Are you sure there isn't an issue with @types/react or @types/react-dom?

@Andrew, I'm not using typescript, but I just added these packages anyway, and there doesn't seem to be a change. The library I'm developing to test this can be found at https://github.com/Ptolemy2002/react-mount-effects.

There's an issue in your package.json. Even though you're not using typescript, having a jsconfig.json file tells your IDE and other tools to type check with jsdoc. Beyond that, there are some errors in your package.json file.
Make sure these versions match:
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": ">=18.0.0",
        "react-dom": ">=18.0.0",
        "@types/react": ">=18.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": ">=18.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0"
    }

And then remove these references to your local files. If they're in your node_modules folder already, there's really no reason to do this.
"react": "file:../node_modules/"
react-dom": "file:../node_modules/react-dom",
"@types/react": "file:../node_modules/@types/react",
"@types/react-dom": "file:../node_modules/@types/react-dom",V

Edit
After checking your package locally just now (12:30pm CST, July 20th), you're still installing a mismatching types package. This is the output from pnpm why..., but this would almost surely be the case for any package manager:
devDependencies:
react 18.3.1
react-dom 18.3.1
└── react 18.3.1 peer
react-mount-effects λ p why react-dom
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

@ptolemy2002/react-mount-effects@0.1.0 /Users/bigsexy/Desktop/react-mount-effects

devDependencies:
react-dom 18.3.1
react-mount-effects λ p why @types/react
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

@ptolemy2002/react-mount-effects@0.1.0 /Users/bigsexy/Desktop/react-mount-effects

devDependencies:
@types/react 18.3.3
@types/react-dom 18.3.0
└── @types/react 18.3.3

If you're going to lock in the types package to a specific version, definitely do the same with react and react-dom themselves. It's a good practice, especially with monorepos that can grow to have a ton of dependencies, but you definitely need to apply it universally.

I removed "jsconfig.json" and also made the package updates you suggested. I'm still getting the same React "rules of hooks" error, but now I also get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')". Do you know what could still be wrong?

Did you install everything again afterwords with pnpm or npm install? Try making those changes to your package.json, then delete the entire node_modules folder and whichever lock file your package manager generates, and then install everything from scratch.

Yes, I've removed both node_modules and package-lock.json files in the root and example projects and reloaded them with npm. There doesn't seem to be a change in behavior.

This is a weird error to get for this cause, but the only other thing I can think to tell you would be to try and set this up as a monorepo with one of the monorepo tools out there like turborepo or lerna.
